# json.dump doesn't dump anything, and leaves me with an empty file | Python

Tags: python, json, file-writing, file-manipulation

I have been trying to dump a dictionary into my JSON file with the `json` library. However, when I dump, the file doesn't show anything inside it. Furthermore, when I read the file (using `open('file').read()`), it shows the data there! Can anyone help me locate this phantom data?

`db = {'aaaa': 'bbbb'} # This is just for testing, but the shape of the actual DB will be about the same.`

```
def write()
    while True:
        with open('C:\\Users\\very\\long\\path\\to\\json-file\\data.json', 'w') as f:
            
            json.dump(db, f)
            sleep(2)
            print('dumped')


Thread(target=write()).start()
```

[image: Data.json showing nothing.]

Other info:
Environment: VSCode
Python version: 3.9.0
Library: json (import json)
Called: inside a thread.
No errors.

Comment: Cloud you share full example? 
P.S. why "data.json" in your path is repeated twice?

Comment: The second time is just for the reading. That was for debugging. The main stuff is the first call. @user3431635

Comment: @user3431635 I iedited the post so that all the code is visible.

Comment: json.dump assumed to dump object, so why you use str(db)?

Comment: another thing I tried to show the data. I'll remove it. @user3431635

Comment: So how you db looks like? Cloud you give full example as I have asked in my first comment?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]; this should also detail how the content is read. The code snippets shown are not complete and contain at least one syntax error and one type error.

Comment: Note that opening a file for writing may truncate it *immediately*, and writes may be delayed until the end of a context manager. In short, seeing how the ``while True:`` loop immediately re-opens the file after the context manager, content may exist for only a split second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct code:

```
import json
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread
db = {'aaaa': 'bbbb'} 

def write():
    while True:
        with open('data2.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(db, f)
        print('dumped')
        sleep(10)


Thread(target=write()).start()
```

In your case, data is written (flushed) into the file and instantly file is reopened for writing. I have moved sleep from "with" statment and now it works

Comment: sure. It works fine on my side.  (you have to add import json,
from time import sleep , from threading import Thread, and 
db = {'aaaa': 'bbbb'} lines

Comment: So I will paste whole code. Please point me out what sintax error it gives on your side.